# MySQL query issue

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
  SELECT count(*) as total, dp.name,dp.id,dp.description, dp.avatar 
  FROM `doctors` d  
  right join departments dp on d.department_id = dp.id 
  group by d.department_id
```

I have to tables: doctors and departments. I want to extract the total number of doctors from each department. This query works fine, it returns me all of the deparments, which have a doctors, but not which does not have. Somehow I want to show all of the departements and a total, which represents the doctors whose belong to a department. How can i do that ?

This is the doctor table:[image]
and this is the departments table [image]

Comment: have a look at this question that will explain you about the different ways of doing join: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join). Also can you show us an example of your data in the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM doctors d WHERE d.department_id = dp.id) AS total, 
  dp.* 
FROM departments AS dp
```

And if you want to use `JOIN` then try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(d.department_id) AS total,
  dp.*
FROM departments AS dp
  LEFT JOIN doctors AS d ON dp.id = d.department_id
GROUP BY dp.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM doctors AS d WHERE d.id = dp.id) as total, dp.name,dp.id,dp.description, dp.avatar 
FROM departments dp
```

there are multiple ways of doing this ofcourse, I would do it like this

i dont think you need to join you just need a count of all the doctors and you dont do anything with the rest of the information

Comment: thx but this returns me at total column just 1 or 0, but i have more then one doctors which belongs to a deparment. Check my post again, I updated it , thx

Comment: your query is right except the where part: WHERE d.department_id = dp.id, Can i do it with join instead of select in select?

Answer (score 0):

In my couple of decades working with SQL I've never used right joins. I've always found the LEFT join easier to read. I also try and return the columns in order of the highest to lowest level of detail and finish with sum's and counts. It reads a lot better.

Try this:

```
SELECT dp.id,dp.name,dp.description, dp.avatar,count(*) as total
FROM departments dp
    LEFT JOIN doctors d  
        on d.department_id = dp.id 
GROUP BY dp.id,dp.name,dp.description, dp.avatar
```

You must always group by every column within your select clause except those that are an aggregation (e.g. sum,count) or a constant.